# Simple code - not outputting message

Tags: php, linux, nginx, hhvm, hacklang

I'm using Hack, which can be found at [hacklang.org](http://hacklang.org/).

Why doesn't the following code :

```
<?hh
    $message = "Hey, lol.";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?= $message ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

output the following text?

`Hey, lol.`

---

There are no errors in the error.log file. And when I "View source", it's blank, just like the page itself.

---

Edit:

Guys, please see the code below in response to your answers. If you visit hacklang.org (see hack tag in this question :) and see the tutorial section on the main page, click through to the Exercise **3** of.. and it clearly shows that you're supposed to use hh and not php to define a hack document:

```
<?hh

// Hack functions are annotated with types.
function my_negation(bool $x): bool {
  return !$x;
}
```

Comment: You should use the <?php opening tag instead of <?hh

Comment: The Hack website itself says you can use hh instead of php and so did the 3 tutorials I used lastnight.

Comment: Unlike PHP, Hack and HTML code do not mix.

Comment: But they don't explain what that actually means. How the hell are we supposed to output freaking values then?

Comment: I think a way to go is to embed XHTML using XHP.

Comment: Something must be wrong with how you have your error reporting set up -- your original file is definitely a parse error and that should be reported somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
    $message = "Hey, lol.";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <? echo $message; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Hack cannot be used as a mix with html the way above.
Try this in stead:

```
<?hh
    $message = "Hey, lol.";
    echo '
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ' . $message . '
    </body>
</html>
';
```

Comment: I've updated my question in response to "use <?php instead". And I was told on another question not to use "<? echo $message ?>" and to just use "<?= $message ?>" Is there an official documentation that does actually address the basics of teh language? Because their code in the manual doesn't work.

Comment: What the fuc* is this ^hit? Ah f*ck this I'm not using Hack. That's just filthy. I can't write code like that - it's horrible! Thanks for your answer and help, @gdahl.

Comment: While the latter example is how you *can* output HTML with Hack, it's far from the recommended way. XHP is our preferred method at Facebook; it's also what the cookbook examples are written in: http://cookbook.hacklang.org/. If you don't want to use XHP, I've heard folks have had great luck with templating engines such as Twig.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong syntax for Hack. Even examples on [their own website](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) imply to use normal php constructs for what you are trying to do. Your code should be:

```
<?php
    $message = "Hey, lol.";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: It looks like Hacklang may require a separate way to produce the results. Try the following:

```
<?hh 
    $message = "Hey, lol.";
    echo '
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang=\"en-us\">
            <head>
                <title>title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                ' . $message . '
            </body>
        </html>';
```

Comment: Note: There seems to be some confusion amongst members in this thread (and apparently whoever downvoted me). Hack integrates with PHP. php tags are acceptable here, and seem to be the standard from what I'm finding on the internet. However, *ideally* the code should work just the same if he replaces `<?php` with `<?hh`.

@Aeron, while <? or <?= are technically acceptable, it is better for dependencies to explicitly use <?php. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use for reasons why.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'm beginning to regret choosing to try out Hack. So far, it feels like I've done nothing but _hack_ it all together to get something to work. But it's still not working - even when I use php stuff.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of it, and I would recommend sticking with pure php for the time being if you are doing development in that scope. What do you mean it's not working?

Comment: The examples on their own website www.hacklang.org (see exercise 3 on the main page tutorial section) tell you to use <?hh to define a hack document!

Comment: Mmm, they have some mixed documentation across the net. My example would be for a standard PHP document. It looks like Hack requires some special information. Will edit answer.

Comment: Looks like @gdahl beat me to it. Oh well, hope some of this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using XHP in hack. See here for an example: https://github.com/hhvm/hack-example-site/blob/master/HomeController.php

Comment: Nah its all good but thanks for your answer I do appreciate it. Ive already decided to give something else a go.

Answer (score -1):

Does Hack support short tags? `<?= ?>`

That might be your issue.

Comment: Thanks gdahl ill look into that now. I was just told to use it that way a few monents ago in another conversation

Comment: Really, just replace `<?=` with `<?hh echo`

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use and [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: @HorsSujet He is using Hack, not PHP.

Comment: It is not hack, it is a second syntax.

Comment: @JRL I just tried your comment out. I tried `<?hh echo` and I also tried `<?hh=` but neither of them worked.

Comment: @HorsSujet No, **HACK IS A LANGUAGE**. I do not mean hack as in "making something just work".

Comment: @JRL (I was talking about <?= not <?hh), see you soon.